# Text next to an image

Tags: html, css

Okay, so, I have a div that is 960 px wide.

I have a picture in that, in a div, that is 640px wide and I want another div with text next to it that is 320px wide. When I do this and float the image left and the other div right, this happens.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qRleq.jpg

The image and the "VOOR WIE" must be in the white section, which has it's min-height set.

How do I fix this?

HTML:

```
<h2 id="pagetitle">ADEMHALING</h2>
<div id="foto"></div><div id="floatright"><h4 id="pagecontent">VOOR WIE</h4></div>
```

CSS:

```
#foto {
display: block;
width: 640px;
background-image: url(../images/ademhaling.png);
background-size: cover;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 320px;
float: left; }
#floatright {
width: 310px;
border-top: #CCC 1px solid;
border-left: #CCC 1px solid;
float: right; }
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez44Q/)

Comment: Could you post your html/css?

Comment: Yes ^ this.  And while you're at it, try putting `div { clear: none; }` in your CSS and see if it helps.

Comment: Edited, added the html and css. div { clear: none; } didn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because your floated element get out of the 'document flow' (this is a normal behavior for floated elements).

What you can do is set a `overflow: hidden` to your white section element, that will force the floated element to stay into the "wrapper".

### [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5nHQ/2/)

Where the `#content` element represent the white section of your site.

---

Succes verder!

Comment: I used your fiddle. The image and the text is inside the white section when i use overflow: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez44Q/2/). You do mean element `#content` as your "white section", right?

Comment: Yes, #content is the white section.

Comment: @LennertLeers Well, tell me what's wrong with this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez44Q/2/) ?

Comment: The "VOOR WIE" has to start at the same height as the picture.  It should be kinda like a sidebar.

Comment: That is an other problem. It's because you use `clear: both` on all the div elements. Remove it and see the result: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ez44Q/3/)

Comment: @LennertLeers I know :$ Glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

add a clear div:

```
<h2 id="pagetitle">ADEMHALING</h2>
 <div id="foto"></div>
 <div id="floatright">
 <h4 id="pagecontent">VOOR WIE</h4>
 <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

to your css add:

```
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding "box-sizing:border-box;" for floatright div

```
#floatright 
{
    width: 320px;
    border-top: #CCC 1px solid;
    border-left: #CCC 1px solid;
    float: right; 
    box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing:border-box; /* Firefox */
}
```